# What is this game with cards you describe, draw, or act out, decided by an electronic unit?

Tags: identify-this-game

Can anyone help me remember the name of this game? We played it around 2005. It was an electronic game with a purple (I think) unit. There were no teams. Each player chose a color. All the participating colors checked in on the unit to start the game. There was no game board. The game then chose a color to take a turn. You would select a card and insert it into the unit. The game then decided if you had to describe it, draw it, or act it out. The game also chose which color you would be doing the card with. It was all completely random. The game unit kept up with the score and at the end announced how many points each color had earned. I think there were two electronic hosts, one male and one female. I distinctly remember the female voice slowly saying, "Maybe you should try to act", slowly sounding out each letter in the word 'act'.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your title so that it is other users coming across the question know what it is about. I suggest something like "What is this game where players describe, draw, or act out things from coloured cars to an electronic host?" or something like that. "I need your help!" is not a very good title for this site format :)

Comment: It's not Cranium Hoopla is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remember playing this game as a kid! I believe it was called "Express Yourself". Hope I helped in some way!

[image]

Comment: Here's the [BGG link for Express Yourself](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7321/express-yourself); it seems to match the description perfectly. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I'm just seeing this. I just ordered it. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Cranium Turbo Edition](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/12875/cranium-turbo-edition)?

[image: image of Cranium Turbo Edition game]

It has an electronic purple unit and 4 different types of activities: Data head (fun facts), Star performer (act & hum), Creative cat (sketch & sculpt), and Word worm (word puzzles).

Comment: No, there was no game board. But thanks for the response!

Comment: @csanlee keep in mind, that most games of this type can be played without a board as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your description reminded me of Taboo. Therefore, I googled for an electronic version of the game and got two hits.

- [Taboo Buzz'd](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IFWSMMS)
- [Electronic Taboo (Platinum Edition)](https://boardgamegeek.com/images/boardgameversion/96586/platinum-edition)

I do not know these versions so I do not know if they match the rest of your description but I hope one of these two is the game you are looking for.

Comment: These aren't what I'm looking for but I like the Electronic Taboo. I think that will be my next game purchase. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It could be Pictionary. Although this does have a board, maybe you have a different version. But in pictionary, you do have 2 different coloured cards and you have to draw what card comes up. The "unit" that you are talking about might be an electronic version of Pictionary where the "unit" gives out a random card.